# How to change password in flask python?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, change-password

I am working on python by using flask framework. I am stuck on 1 condition. Actually I am working on Update User Password / Change Password module in flask. I have to match user current password (just type password in the text field) with old password How can I apply condition? or What condition will be? Your suggestions would be appreciated.

I have applied these conditions and they are working fine

```
if password_old == updated_password and new_password1 == updated_password:
                data = { 'updateUserPassword': '1', 'password_update_message': 'You have entered old password. Please try another one.', 'contents': '0' }
            else:
                data = { 'updateUserPassword': '1', 'password_update_message': ' Your password has been updated successfully.', 'contents': '1' }
```

Please suggest me how can I the other condition?

[image]

Comment: Just as a note, you should not store the password in plain text, so you cannot compare a entered password with one from your database. You should hash the password.

Comment: How can I use hash password with this code?

Comment: Have a look at the Werkzeug documentation - https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/utils/#module-werkzeug.security  - especially generate_password_hash and check_password_hash - I used these methods for my last Flask app.